# Download com tag <a> em webview

Tags: java, android, webview

Olá!

Tenho um webview funcionando, estou tentando criar a seguinte tag html:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < nm.size(); i++) {
     html.append("<a https://example.com.br/ret/AttachedFile.do?command=showFile&generatedId=").append(id.get(i)).append(">").append(nm.get(i)).append("</a><br />");
 }
```

Que ficaria assim:

```
<a https://example.com.br/ret/AttachedFile.do?command=showFile&generatedId=64>Download archive</a><br />
```

No entanto, quando clico no item para baixar o conteúdo, nada acontece...
O que tenho que fazer, para que o clique baixe o arquivo com o url informado?
Obrigado!

Comment: Está faltando o href antes do endereço que você deseja acessar                         html.append("<a href="https://example.com.br/ret/AttachedFile.do?command=showFile&generatedId=").append(id.get(i)).append(">").append(nm.get(i)).append("</a><br />");

Answer (score 0):

Conforme comentado pelo Alisson, você precisa colocar o atributo `href` na tag:

```
html.append("<a href=\"https://example.com.br/ret/AttachedFile.do?command=showFile&generatedId=").append(id.get(i)).append("\">").append(nm.get(i)).</a><br />")
```

Note as barras invertidas nos lugares onde tem aspas literais (`\"`)